# Can't read datafile collected using Mastodon API

Tags: python, dataframe, api, rate-limiting, mastodon

I used the people directory API from Mastodon (https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/directory/) to collect all the accounts from an instance. I created a loop with the `offset` parameter, so that it collects all the accounts that the instance is aware of. This is my code:

```
import os
import requests
import json
import schedule
import logging
import time
from datetime import date, datetime
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry

# The base API endpoint for Mastodon instances
API_BASE_URL = 'https://{instance_name}/api/v1/directory?limit=80'

# Access token for the Mastodon API
ACCESS_TOKEN = "x"


# Configure the logging module
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=f'mas.to {datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.log',  # Name of the log file
    level=logging.INFO,  # Log level
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',  # Log message format
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'  # Date format
)


def save_to_file(instance_name, date, offset=0):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"}
    api_endpoint = f'https://{instance_name}/api/v1/directory?limit=80' + f"&offset={offset}"
    try:
        response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers, timeout=60)
        logging.info(f"Request made for instance {instance_name}, offset {offset}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logging.error(f"HTTP error occurred for instance {instance_name}, offset {offset}: {err}")
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred for instance {instance_name}, offset {offset}: {err}")
    else:
        try:
            filename = f'{instance_name}_people_top10_{date}.json'
            filePath = os.getcwd() + "/top10 people/" + filename
            
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filePath), exist_ok=True)
            with open(filePath, 'a') as f:
                json.dump(response.json(), f)
                
            # Check if response is empty
            if not response.json():
                logging.info(f"Reached end of directory for instance {instance_name}")
                return False
                
            # Continue with the next batch of accounts
            return True
            
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(f"Error occurred while saving data for instance {instance_name}, offset {offset}: {err}")


@sleep_and_retry
@limits(20, period=1)
def directory():
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    logging.info(f"Started data collection at {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")
    offset = 0
    while save_to_file('mas.to', now, offset):
        offset += 80
    logging.info(f"Finished data collection at {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory()
```

I have two issues:

1. for the instance i used in the code, it does run until it has collected all the accounts in the directory. However, when i want to read the code inn python, it gives me the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 210632 (char 210631)` or `ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)`
2. The second issue I face is that if I use another instance (for example mastodon.social) i get an error in my log file that there were too many requests and then stops collecting the data. I added a ratelimit function as well and set the call and period bot to 1 as the mastodon API has a ratelimit of 300 requests per 5 minutes.

I have already tried different methods to read my file and I still get the same error messages if I try to read only a few lines of the datafile. For the API method I also tried playing around with the number of calls and periods but I still get the same problem

Can anyone help me out? How can I fix both issues? Kinda desperate at the moment as I need this to work for my thesis.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We cannot see the data that your code has collected, so we are unable to help with the JSONDecodeError - what is at the line and column that is referenced? is it valid JSON?